# HTML button link is not clickable

Tags: html, css

I inherited this pretty messy site to revamp for a client. There's alot of weird stuff in the css, but I can't figure out this one. The "buttons" on the homepage (actually links) are not clickable and I can't figure out why. Here's the code.

HTML

```
<a class="btn orange solid" src="www.example.com">LEARN MORE</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    background: transparent;
} 

a {
    color: #01a1dd;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: inherit;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 12px 29px 12px 29px;
    letter-spacing: .25px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn.orange {
    color: #f98803;
    border: 2px solid #f98803;
}

.btn.solid {
    background: #f98803;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
```

All the other buttons on the site are clickable, just not these two on the homepage.

Here's a codepen with the code, and the same issue. https://codepen.io/kathryncrawfor/pen/NwLRoP

Comment: The attribute is `href`, not `src`. Voting to close as a typo. A [validator](https://validator.nu) would have identified this problem.

Comment: Well, this is facepalm moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use `href` instead of src.

Answer (score 2):

But you are using `src` and not `href` in the link tag, try to modify

```
<a class="btn orange solid" src="http://cp.digitalreachagency.com/company/it-professional/">LEARN MORE</a>
```

with

```
<a class="btn orange solid" href="http://cp.digitalreachagency.com/company/it-professional/">LEARN MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You used wrong attribute to set the link. You should use `href`.

`<a class="btn orange solid" href="your/link/here">Link text</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

use href instead src

```css
a {
    background: transparent;
} 

a {
    color: #01a1dd;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: inherit;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 12px 29px 12px 29px;
    letter-spacing: .25px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn.orange {
    color: #f98803;
    border: 2px solid #f98803;
}

.btn.solid {
    background: #f98803;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero-split">
        <h1 class="homepage-header">Make your IT Partnerships Productive</h1>
        <div class="persona" style="background-image: url('http://www.cloudphysics.com/static/uploads/2014/03/hero-left.png');">
          <div>
            <h2>I AM AN<br><strong>IT PROFESSIONAL</strong></h2>
            <a class="btn orange solid" href="http://cp.digitalreachagency.com/company/it-professional/">LEARN MORE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="persona" style="background-image: url('http://www.cloudphysics.com/static/uploads/2014/03/hero-right.png');">
          <div>
            <h2>I AM A<br><strong>SOLUTION PROVIDER</strong></h2>
            <a class="btn orange solid" href="http://cp.digitalreachagency.com/company/solution-provider/">LEARN MORE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor Tag needs a HREF attribute for it to work as a link

```
<a class="btn orange solid" href="http://cp.digitalreachagency.com/company/it-professional/">LEARN MORE</a>
```

the above should work